# Tensorflow 2.0 model checkpoint files to .pb/onnx file

Tags: tensorflow, onnx

For model checkpoint files (usually consist of `.meta`, `.data`, `.index`) generated from TF-2.0, how can I convert it to `onnx` or `pb` file?
since I found most of the existing tools, such as `tf2onnx` only support TF-1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf2onnx supports tf2, saved models, and checkpoint files.  I would recommend making a saved model:

`model.save("path")`

Then use tf2onnx command line:

`tf2onnx.convert --saved-model path/to/model --output model.onnx --opset 12`

https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx#--saved-model